# Generalization of topological realization of simplicial sets to general categories.

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, simplicial-stuff

Given a functor $U: \Delta \rightarrow \textbf C$ from the simplex category into $\textbf C$, I want to show that if $\mid -\mid$ is "geometric realization" of a simplicial set in $\textbf C$ given by the left Kan extension (assuming it exists)

[image]

the diagram commutes. I.e $\mid \text{yoneda}(-)\mid = U(-)$. This is true for the topological case ($\textbf{C} = \text{Top})$ but I don't know about the general case.

Comment: The result quoted here (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3435524/extension-of-a-functor-by-colimits-cisinski-higher-categories-and-homotopical/) is related. The idea is that in a nice case (if $C$ is cocomplete) $|-|$ is just an extension by colimits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true in considerable generality. If $y:A\to B$ is fully faithful and $f:A\to C$, then $Lan_u f\circ u$ is naturally isomorphic to $f$ whenever $Lan_u$ is a pointwise left Kan extension, for instance, whenever $C$ is cocomplete. The reason is that $Lan_u f(b)$ is the colimit of the diagram indexed by the comma category $u/b$ whose value at $u(a)\to b$ is simply $f(a)$. When $u$ is fully faithful, $u/u(a)$ is equivalent to $A/a$, so has a terminal object $id_a:u(a)\to u(a)$, and the colimit is the value $f(a)$ taken at $id_a$.